# Access the main window datacontext from a new created window

Tags: c#, wpf, window, datacontext

In my MainWindow I create a new instance of a class containing different settings. After setting the parameters of the class, I set the datacontext = to that class.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

 private MeasConSettings mMeasConSettings = new MeasConSettings();

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = mMeasConSettings;
  }

  private void MenuComm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {// See code below}

}
```

Now I also have a function to open a new window, this window contains a textbox who's text should be bound to the datacontext of the MainWindow.

```
    private void MenuComm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrmSettings newWindow = new FrmSettings();
        newWindow.DataContext = mMeasConSettings;
        newWindow.TxtComm.Text = mMeasConSettings.CommSettings;
        newWindow.Show();
    }
```

This code fills in the textbox from the newWindow with the right content, BUT it does not get bound propery since the datacontext does not get updated after changing the text in the textbox (TxtComm in the new created window).

An example of the XAML code for the textbox:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="2,0"  Name="TxtComm" DataContext="{Binding Path=CommSettings, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

"CommSettings" is a member of the MeasConsettings class

```
public class MeasConSettings
{
    private string mCommSettings;

    public string CommSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return mCommSettings;
        }
        set
        {
            mCommSettings = value;
        }
    }

    public MeasConSettings()
    {
        CommSettings = "Com5:19200,8,n,1";
    }
}
```

My problem is how can I adjust the value mMeasConSettings.CommSettings (defined in my MainWindow) in my newWindow (Which is created after pressing a button), If I change the textbox value in my newWindow, the value stored in mMeasConSettings.CommSettings should also be changed.

PS: I'm new to WPF so any advice is welcome!

Comment: I don't see a binding being created in your code. You need to bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to the property in your `DataContext` which should be changed with a TwoWay-binding. Your XAML with the `TextBox` should have something like `<TextBox Text="{Binding CommSettings, Mode=TwoWay}" />`.

Comment: @odyss-jii Thanks after changing the XAML of the textbox to `<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="2,0"  Name="TxtComm" Text="{Binding Path=CommSettings, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />` IT WORKED!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, you need to bind the `Text` property of your `TextBox` to the property of the `DataContext` which you want to update. Your XAML should thus be something like:

```
<TextBox ... Text="{Binding CommSettings, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Note that I am binding the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to the property `CommSettings` of your `DataContext`. And your `C#`-code for the click event should be:

```
private void MenuComm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrmSettings newWindow = new FrmSettings();
    newWindow.DataContext = mMeasConSettings;
    newWindow.Show();
}
```

We only need to set the `DataContext` here. Note that the `DataContext` is passed along to child elements, so the `TextBox` will have the same `DataContext` as its parent unless specifically set to something else.

Answer (score 1):

use static property:

```
class Demo
{
    public static string SomeSettings {get;set;}
    private onLoad()
    {
        SomeSettings=... //Init here
    }
}
```

In other file:

```
Demo.SomeSettings=....
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a property to the second window and pass the parameter to the property through the constructor. My code passing dictionary

In MainWindow:

```
var fileContent = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
  ["Salutation"] = "Test",
};
var w_SelectionWindow2 = new SelectionWindow2(fileContent);
w_SelectionWindow2.Show();
Hide();
```

In Second window (I named it `w_SelectionWindow2`)

```
public partial class SelectionWindow2 : Window
{
  public Dictionary<string, string> FileContent { get; init; }
  public SelectionWindow2(Dictionary<string, string> fileContent)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    FileContent = fileContent;
    TestBlock.Text = FileContent["Salutation"]; //Result is "Test" in your TextBlock  (<TextBlock x:Name="TestBlock"></TextBlock>)
  }

  public SelectionWindow2()  //optional default constructor
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```